# AH00526: Syntax error line 51 modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf

Tags: debian, apache2, mod-security

I am configuring modsecurity-crs for my apache2 server running on debian 8 jessie. After installing modsecurity and making symbolic links for both base_rules and optional_rules, apache2 cannot restart. Using

```
sudo journalctl | tail
```

shows the error message

> 'AH00526: Syntax error on line 51 of
>   ../modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf'.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the answer here.
-   https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/commit/e2fbef4ce89fed0c4dd338002b9a090dd2f6491d
Essentially there's a bug in the crs module. You need to delete the word 'chain' from line 49 of modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf You can do this using 'sudo nano modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf' and then scroll to the line, delete the words 'chain' then press Ctrl+O then Ctrl+X
After editing restart the apache service with 'sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start